# Lots of functions involving network operations

Tags: java, android

I have a function which performs a request to a REST API, which uses httpPost. So after using some nameValuePair and UrlEncodedFormEntity magic to set up everything, I have this code:

```
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        // parsing the response here
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This was originally put into a function (a public String), where it uses the response of the REST API to return an access token. This function lives in a class which is only used for commuication with the API. From my main activity, I create an instance of this class and then call:

```
    String accesstoken = ApiHandler.login();
```

From MainActivity. This access token is required to do anything else in the application, so this has to be done before the application can continue. I pass the context of the application to ApiHandler to be able to show toast messages and AlertDialogs from the ApiHandler class. However, I have a few issues now:

How can I keep the screen on a progressdialog which was called from the login function in ApiHandler until I have the accesstoken? I tried using a Thread, but the communication between the thread, the login function as a whole and the main UI activity which calls the login function seems to require a lot of work. Furthermore, and more importantly, it requires me to use thread.join() because the application can not do anything if it does not have the access token which is given by login(). Logcat tells me that this seems to be freezing the UI, as I get a message saying it skipped 30 to 50 frames and something may be blocking the UI thread.

Another problem is that the ApiHandler has a lot of functions because the API has a lot of different calls, so something like AsyncTask would make the code unreadable as it would result in lots of Asynctasks, and every function returns different types of data. Writing an entire Asynctask for every function in ApiHandler, along with its own doInBackground, onPostExecute and onPreExecute would make things a lot more difficult than they should be it seems.

So what is the easiest way to run code from a non-activity class, which requires network connections without freezing the UI thread, and of which the response should actually be synchronous, as a lot of operations in the app can't be done asynchronously, and does not clutter the code when I have 150 functions for different API calls, each with their own function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some android lib for asynchronous HTTP operation. [Retrofit from sqaure](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is awesome one.

**From Retrofit documentation**

> It Uses annotations to describe the HTTP request:
>
> - URL parameter replacement and query parameter support
> - Object conversion to request body (e.g., JSON, protocol buffers)
> - Multipart request body and file upload

**Sample Code**

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}


RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);


List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Comment: It took me some time to understand how Retrofit works, but I finally got it up and running, and it is doing a beautiful job and makes the code very clean indeed! Thank you!